# Remove the Product Count on Woocommerce Categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

pic http://goo.gl/hnRfG9
I want to hide  product count form category : I tried this in `functions.php` of theme

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', 'woo_remove_category_products_count' );
function woo_remove_category_products_count() {  
  return;  
}
```

But it does not work. I edit this from theme editor and also from directory to make sure its written.

Answer (score 1):

That one works for me:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', 'jk_hide_category_count' );
function jk_hide_category_count() {
// No count
}
```

Picked it up in WooC tuts somewhere.

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aforementioned filter, but you need to use the right arguments in your callback function:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', function($html, $category){
  return '';
}, 2, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the count use this filter. This is official filter provided by woocommerce team - https://woocommerce.com/document/hide-sub-category-product-count-in-product-archives/

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', '__return_false' );
```

Add it in your functions.php file of your active theme.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
/** Remove Showing results functionality site-wide */
function woocommerce_result_count() {
        return;
}
```